# Button to switch scenes on click

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, uibutton, scene

So I am really struggling with figuring out how to switch scenes at the press of a button. Basically, I want to make a "Start Game" button. There are lots of google answers, and none of them seem to help. Either there is a syntax error or the app crashes. Anyway, here is what I have going. I have a gameviewcontroller that correctly makes my button, and it successfully communicates with a method on button press (for things like printing a character to console). Now, in my Title.m (the scene I start at), I have a method like so:

```
-(void) gScene { 
    GameScene* gameScene = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
    [self.view presentScene:gameScene];
}
```

I also have the method in my Title.h, which is imported into the GameViewController.
In my GameViewController, the method linked with my button press is called startGame. This is what startGame looks like:

```
-(void)startGame { 
    Title* title = [[Title alloc] init];
    [title gScene];
}
```

I want, on button press, for the scene to switch from my Title to my GameScene. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to initialize your view controller with an interface. Are you using nibs or storyboards?

Answer (score 0):

If using nibs:

```
GameScene *vc = [[GameScene alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If using storyboards:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YOUR_STORYBOARD_NAME" bundle:nil];
GameScene *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER_OF_IB_VC"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If programmatically creating the scene: ([Apple Documentation)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html)

```
   UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   levelViewController = [[LevelViewController alloc] init];
   window.rootViewController = levelViewController;
   [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Your issue lies in the "self.size" code you use to set the bounds of the frame. The third example should help you out. Cheers

Comment: I made everything programmically. I didn't use nib or storyboard. I appreciate the response, but still am a bit lost.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I am still unsure how to apply the programmatically created scene code you posted. Would I put that code (or rather, code like it applied to my project) in the gScene method, or should I put it in the startGame method and forgo the gScene method completely? This is what I am trying:

UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
levelViewController = [[Title alloc] init];
window.rootViewController = levelViewController;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: Sorry for the formatting above, ctrl k (or the mac equivalent, or command k) is not working for some reason. anyway, I try that and run into issues: That levelViewController is an undeclared identifier, and Title being incompatible types with UIViewController. I replace Title with GameViewController out of curiosity, and same problem. I am unsure as to how to apply your code, and I have read the documentation.

Comment: Are you using the Cocos2d library? Just curious, if so then it's a different syntax. Also, don't use 'levelViewController' that's just a sample from Apple. You would want to instantiate your second scene from this line.